# Convert Resultset to string and place in list

Tags: python, xml, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to convert the values in my list to normal strings such as

```
listy = [['value1','value2','value3'],['value1','value2','value3'],[
```

I initialized an empty list `listy = []` and found all the `<a>` using find_all('a') and produced this as output

```
listy = [[... <a>value1</a>, <a>value2</a>, <a>value3</a>, ...],[...<a>value4</a>, <a>value5</a>, <a>value6</a>, ...],[]]
```

I tried using `item.find_all('a').string` however I was given this error.

`AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'string'`

Meaning the ResultSet cannot be converted to string.

I then search how to convert `ResultSet` to `String`

I found `unicode.join(u'\n', map(unicode,listy))`

However when I tried this i get this error

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'`

I most likely get this error when I appended the list to get my original listy

How could i convert the `find_all('a')` to `string` types and append them into a list?

My XML file:

```
<Z>
  <Y>
    <x>
      <a> value1 </a>
      <a> value2 </a>
      <a> value3 </a>
    </x>
  </Y>
  <Y>
    <x>
      <a> value4 </a>
      <a> value5 </a>
      <a> value6 </a>
    </x>
  </Y>
  <Y>
  </Y>
</Z>
```

I'm trying to create a list in the following format

`listy = [['value1','value2','value3'],['value4','value5','value6'],[]]`

Comment: I think you're making some confusion here. what's the input data you have? and how you populate your list?

Comment: Yes, please show us the code you are using currently we have an idea what you are attempting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the string of each *individual* link, not of the whole result set.

Loop over the set and fetch `.string` *per element*:

```
[link.string for link in item.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: I was just about to paste my code, when I see this. Beaten by 42 seconds. Python _has_ indeed become competitive.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Hey, I came to this question late. :-) I came here when it was about 10 minutes old.

Comment: I'm still a bit new to python but right now I have `listy.append(z.y.x[link.string for link in item.find_all('a')])` Not sure if I'm using this correctly

Comment: `listy.append([link.string for link in item.find_all('a')])`; the `[... for ... in ...]` is a list comprehension that produces a list of values.

Comment: @Liondancer: without seeing the full line of code that is very hard to assess; it depends on what is there **before** the `for`, Python only knows things are wrong by the time it gets to parsing `for` and that is unexpected based on what preceded.

Comment: Do you think it ahs to do with the fact that I also have `for item in z.y.find_all('x')`. Then for each `item` I use the line `listy.append(item[link.string for link in item.find_all('a')])`

Comment: Why do you keep putting `item` in front of the list comprehension? That is not valid syntax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40240/discussion-between-liondancer-and-martijn-pieters)